# Вопрос по ConstraintLayout'у

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-sdk, android-constraintlayout

У меня проблема одна, помогите пожалуйста.

Есть `constraintLayout` в нем `textView`,  `listView` и кнопка внизу. Все по вертикали вниз стоят. Привязал друг к другу. Ширину и высоту `listView` указываю как `match_constraint` в `0dp`. В итоге `listView` типо не успевает заполниться данными и высота реально `0dp`, его нету.

Пробовал ставить высоту `wrap_content` - работает, но пропадает разделитель(`divider`) между "итемами". Думал может это из-за того, что неправильно высота у `listView` указывается. (Где-то в нете вычитал такое).

Как это решается? Указывать фиксированные значения не хочется все таки.

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.goindriver.ui.custom.TextViewRobotoMedium
    android:id="@+id/msg_choose_reason"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/msg_choose_reason"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_close"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/mobility_icon_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/mobility_icon_height"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rippled_grey_bg"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_reason"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/frameLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/msg_choose_reason" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/inride_button_height"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/listview_reason">

    <include layout="@layout/view_blue_button" />

</FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

view_blue_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/btnBlue"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_blue_bg"
    android:theme="@style/BlueButtonTheme" />
```

И выглядит так, без списка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну у вас просто зависимости не верно указаны скорей всего, сейчас не видно что делает инклюд на view_blue_button, и в картинке Dialog это верстка для диалога ?

Comment: Да, это диалогФрагмент. Внутри инклуда просто кнопка со стиялми. Обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

```
    android:layout_width="0dp"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/msg_choose_reason"
```

Выставьте высоту `0dp` и укажите `dividerHeight` в `1dp`.

Comment: это предложение как вариант решения Вашей проблемы. Кстати, у Вас зачем-то одни и те же строчки в отступах, `layout_marginLeft`  - то же, что и `layout_marginStart`, и так далее)

Comment: Пожалуйста, не используйте вопросительные формы предложений в ответе. Изменяйте/дополненяйте сообшение кнопкой [правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1181739/edit).